# libxmljs "could not locate the bindings file" error (Windows)

Tags: node.js, npm, libxml-js

I'm using a module called [gulp-xml-editor](https://github.com/morou/gulp-xml-editor) which uses [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs). All working well on our Macs, but when I try on our Windows machine, I get: *"Could not locate the bindings file"* referring to the bindings dependency of libxmljs:

```
C:\HiddenPath\App Source>gulp clean
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:91
  throw err
        ^
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Debug\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\out\Debug\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\Debug\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\out\Release\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\Release\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\build\default\xmljs.node
 ÔåÆ C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\compiled\0.12.7\win32\ia32\xmljs.node
    at bindings (C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:88
:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\lib\bindings.js:1:99)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\api\register\node.js:214:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\gulp-xml-editor\node_modules\libxmljs\index.js:4:16)
```

Set up is:

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Visual Studio Professional 2013
- Node v0.12.7
- NPM v2.11.3
- gulp-xml-editor v2.2.1
- libxmljs v0.14.2
- Python v2.7

The only file in `libxmljs\build\` is `config.gypi` (which seems strange because there are more files there on my Mac).

Earlier on I was getting different errors. Firstly, libxmljs couldn't find the 'bindings' module at all - presumably because its 'npm install' had failed. Trying to `npm install` it directly gave an `ETIMEOUT` on `node-gyp rebuild`. Re-installing node-gyp and/or installing Python v2.7 (instead of v3) fixed that though. Now `npm install` seems to work OK except for some warnings:

```
C:\HiddenPath\App Source>npm install
npm WARN package.json HiddenAppName@0.2.0 No license field.

> libxmljs@0.14.2 install C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs>if
 not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modul
es\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
 else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  buf.c
  catalog.c
  chvalid.c
  dict.c
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\dict.c(173): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from
 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.v
cxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\catalog.c(977): warning C4013: 'open' undefined; assumin
g extern returning int [C:\HiddenPath\App Source
\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\catalog.c(998): warning C4013: 'read' undefined; assumin
g extern returning int [C:\HiddenPath\App Source
\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\catalog.c(999): warning C4013: 'close' undefined; assumi
ng extern returning int [C:\HiddenPath\App Sourc
e\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\dict.c(237): warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismat
ch [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxml
js\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\dict.c(305): warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismat
ch [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxml
js\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
  encoding.c
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\buf.c(674): warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different
from declaration [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_
modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
  entities.c
  error.c
  globals.c
  hash.c
  HTMLparser.c
  HTMLtree.c
  legacy.c
  list.c
  parser.c
  parserInternals.c
  pattern.c
  relaxng.c
  SAX2.c
  SAX.c
  tree.c
  threads.c
  uri.c
  valid.c
  xinclude.c
  xlink.c
  xmlIO.c
  xmlmemory.c
  xmlmodule.c
  xmlreader.c
  xmlregexp.c
  xmlsave.c
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(668): warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible t
ypes - from 'stat *' to '_stat64i32 *' [C:\Users\Pebble Code\Documents\ByBox Er
skine\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(736): warning C4996: 'GetVersionExA': was declar
ed deprecated [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_mod
ules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(433)
  : see declaration of 'GetVersionExA'
  xmlschemas.c
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(822): warning C4013: 'read' undefined; assuming
extern returning int [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\n
ode_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(843): warning C4013: 'write' undefined; assuming
 extern returning int [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\
node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
  xmlschemastypes.c

..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(861): warning C4013: 'close' undefined; assuming
 extern returning int [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\
node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(3811): warning C4013: 'getcwd' undefined; assumi
ng extern returning int [C:\HiddenPath\App Sourc
e\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(3811): warning C4047: '!=' : 'int' differs in le
vels of indirection from 'void *' [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
  xmlstring.c
  xmlunicode.c
  xmlwriter.c
  xpath.c
  xpointer.c
c:\users\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(71): warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from de
claration (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(74): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'co
nst uint64_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpa
th.c) [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\lib
xmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(185): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'int64
_t' to 'const size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\b
uild\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(334): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'const
 int64_t' to 'const size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpat
h.c) [C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libx
mljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(340): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'const
 int64_t' to 'size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\b
uild\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(364): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'const
 int64_t' to 'size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\b
uild\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(469): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'int64
_t' to 'const size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\b
uild\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(470): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'int64
_t' to 'const size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\b
uild\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(471): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'int64
_t' to 'const size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\b
uild\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
c:\hiddenpath\app source\node_modules\libxmljs\v
endor\libxml\timsort.h(480): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'int64
_t' to 'const size_t', possible loss of data (..\..\..\vendor\libxml\xpath.c) [
C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\b
uild\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]
  libxml.vcxproj -> C:\HiddenPath\App Source\nod
  e_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\\libxml.lib
  libxmljs.cc
  xml_attribute.cc
  xml_document.cc
  xml_element.cc
  xml_comment.cc
  xml_namespace.cc
  xml_node.cc
  xml_sax_parser.cc
  xml_syntax_error.cc
  xml_xpath_context.cc
     Creating library C:\HiddenPath\App Source\n
  ode_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.lib and object C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.
  exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  xmljs.vcxproj -> C:\HiddenPath\App Source\node
  _modules\libxmljs\build\Release\\xmljs.node
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@2.0.2 should be installed with -g
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\HiddenPath\App Sourc
e\node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\istanbul\node_modules\handlebars\node_modul
es\uglify-js requires async@'~0.2.6' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\HiddenPath\App Sourc
e\node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\istanbul\node_modules\async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.4.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\HiddenPath\App Sourc
e\node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\istanbul\node_modules\handlebars\node_modul
es\uglify-js requires optimist@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\HiddenPath\App Sourc
e\node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\optimist,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.1

C:\HiddenPath\App Source>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just needed to clear out `node_modules` and do a clean `npm install`!

(I thought I had done that, but it's because I'm not used to Windows and didn't realise `del` wasn't deleting the directory! Then I had an issue with filenames that were too long but that was fixed by this: https://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete)